# Where is the the full tokens list for a site?

Tags: 8, tokens, meta-tags

In the [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module UI it uses tokens but only shows a small list of tokens that are relative to the site information rather than the full content tokens which it can use, in D7 there was an admin token page so you can check values.

Where is this in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I see its one of those things that you once you know.

Enable modules:

- [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token)
- Help (core)

Navigate to the page: `/admin/help/token`.

Comment: Take note that this page shows *all* available tokens with taking context into account. You won't be able to use every single token displayed. For instance tokens that start with `node` or `block` are unlikely to know _which_ node or block you're referring to.